# angularJS Resetting $Scope Values On Button Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AngularJS SPA what contains a text input on a modal, on Page load the modals inputs are set to their desired initial state through a scope function which is called.

**Modal**

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="PatientName" name="PatientName" id="PatientName" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="setvals()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module("TrollyPatientApp", ['TrollyPatientFilters']);

app.controller("NewPartientModalController", function ($scope, $filter) {
    console.log("controller Loaded...")
    $scope.setvals = function () {
        console.log($scope);
        console.log("Setting Intial New Patient Values.")
        $scope.PatientName = "john";
        $scope.setDateAsNowCB = true; //True = Readonly, false = enabled.
        $scope.ArrivalDateInEd = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');//Injecting the date (through the filter) into the ArrivalDateInED field.
        console.log($scope);
    }

    $scope.setvals();
});
```

When the `close` button is clicked on the modal i want it to reset all the values back to default.

At present it does this by calling `setvals()`. I can see it being called from the debug console however it doesn't seem to effect the input value....

Answer (score 0):

On load you should create a object `patient` that would have all the information about the patient, store it inside some variable on init. & on reset rebind that copy to the actual `patient` model.

**Controller**

```
app.controller("NewPartientModalController", function ($scope, $filter) {
    console.log("controller Loaded...")
    $scope.patient = {};
    $scope.setvals = function () {
        console.log($scope);
        console.log("Setting Intial New Patient Values.")
        $scope.patient.PatientName = "john";
        $scope.patient.setDateAsNowCB = true; //True = Readonly, false = enabled.
        $scope.patient.ArrivalDateInEd = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');//Injecting the date (through the filter) into the ArrivalDateInED field.
        //save copy of initial object in some variable
        $scope.copyOfInitialPatient = angular.copy($scope.patient);
    }

    $scope.reset = function(){
        //assign initial copy again to patient object.
        $scope.patient = angular.copy($scope.copyOfInitialPatient);
    }

    $scope.setvals();
});
```

Comment: @tornup does it helped?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `$scope.PatientName = "john";` outside of `$scope.setvals` for first, then changing value in `setvals()` will work.

```js
var app = angular.module("TrollyPatientApp", []);

app.controller("NewPartientModalController", function ($scope, $filter) {
    console.log("controller Loaded...")
    $scope.PatientName = "john";
    $scope.setvals = function () {
        console.log($scope);
        console.log("Setting Intial New Patient Values.")
        $scope.PatientName = "john";
        $scope.setDateAsNowCB = true; //True = Readonly, false = enabled.
        $scope.ArrivalDateInEd = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');//Injecting the date (through the filter) into the ArrivalDateInED field.
        console.log($scope);
    }

    $scope.setvals();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="TrollyPatientApp" ng-controller="NewPartientModalController">
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="PatientName" name="PatientName" id="PatientName" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="setvals()" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</body>
```